# Hi, I am trying to convert categorical to numerical values but ending up with error could not find function "%>%"

Tags: r

```
trainData_df %>%
  select(name,loan_status) %>%
  mutate (Y = ifelse(loan_status=="Charged Off","1","0"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to load the package `dplyr`

```
#install.packages('dplyr') # if not installed, install it
library(dplyr)
trainData_df %>%
     select(name,loan_status) %>%
     mutate (Y = ifelse(loan_status=="Charged Off", 1, 0))
```

---

Also, `ifelse`, is not needed

```
trainData_df %>%
     select(name,loan_status) %>%
     mutate(Y = +(loan_status == "Charged Off"))
```

Comment: If you want Y to be numeric remove the quotes from "1", "0"